# C++ delete what wchar_t* points to

Tags: c++, delete-operator, wchar-t

Title might be confusing. This is a simple thing, but I have searched and tried for an hour now. I have tried everything I have found.

code:

```
void test() {


// Convert
wchar_t* wcBuff;
wstring value = convert::stringToWideChar(str);
wcBuff = (wchar_t*)value.c_str();

// Draw Text
g->DrawString(wcBuff,...);

// Clean
delete wcBuff;


}
```

The delete causes the program to crash.

Comment: I haven't used `wstring` before, but are you sure you need to cast the return of `c_str`?

Comment: @Neil Kirk Yeah, without it, this is the error on the following line: `[Error] invalid cast from type 'std::wstring {aka std::basic_string<wchar_t>}' to type 'wchar_t*'`

Comment: `wcBuff = value.c_str();`

Comment: @NeilKirk ah, gotcha, that created this error: `[Error] invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*'`

Comment: Now change to `const wchar_t* wcBuff` C-style casts hide errors, avoid them! `delete wcBuff;` is also bad. You can't delete the internal data of string from the outside.

Comment: @NeilKirk nice, no cast now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't explicitly delete `wcBuff`. It points to memory that belongs to `value`, and will be deleted when `value` falls out of scope.

Consider this code:

```
#include <cstdlib>

class alloc
{
    char* memory;

public:
    alloc() { memory = static_cast<char*>(std::malloc(32)); }
    char* get_buff() { return memory; }
    ~alloc() { std::free(memory); }
};

int main()
{
    alloc x;
    char* y = x.get_buff();

    delete y;
}
```

In this example, the `alloc` class uses a mechanism other than `new`/`delete` to allocate and deallocate memory (old C functions, in this case). Calling `delete y` in `main` causes a crash. Since `main` is a function, and `x` is allocated as one of the function's local variables, `x.~alloc()` will be called when `main` exits, freeing the memory that `x` owns.

Comment: that code is within a function, so is the function going to clean up before it ends?

Comment: You’re discovering the joys of RAII.  The `alloc` object `x` is created and destroyed automatically.  As for `y`?  That’s a shallow copy of the buffer in `alloc`, so the buffer will become invalid as soon as anybody deletes it.  Fortunately, the scope of `y` is the same as the scope of `x`, so they’ll both be deleted at the same time.  However, this means you can’t return `y`, because it’s really a pointer to a temporary variable.  If you need a smart pointer that will delete the memory as soon as the last copy is destroyed, and not before, there’s `smart_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

You must not free the memory yourself, because you didn't allocated it yourself.

The `(wchar_t*)value.c_str()` statement returns a pointer to memory that is owned by `wstring` and will be released automatically in its [destructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/~basic_string/) when the function ends (when `value` goes out of scope).

Answer (score 1):

The memory buffer you get from .c_str() is managed by the wstring itself. You should not free it. It gets freed by the destructor of wstring.

As well only pointers allocated with the new operator should/can get freed using the delete operator. As a c string it's probably memory allocated using malloc() which get's freed by free(). But this is an implementation detail of your standard library. Just don't free the memory on your own.

Comment: That code is within a function, is it still going to get cleaned before the function ends?

Comment: It doesn't get freed before value gets out of scope. When value gets out of scope the destructor of wstring is called for value freeing the memory. If you want to make sure its freed before you could enclose the block where it should be valid in braces. But in most cased you should not need to worry about that.